# How to install Ruby 2.1.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I dont know how to install the latest Ruby on Ubuntu.

First I installed the default Ruby 1.9.3, using

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Then I tried to install the 2.0 version using

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0
```

My version of Ruby is still "ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux])"

What should I do?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34523631/4233593) was very helpful for installing the ruby version manager, which allows you to checkout and use any version you want whenever you want in your home environment without need for `sudo`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

First of all, install the prerequisite libraries:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Then install rbenv, which is used to install Ruby:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
```

Then (optional) tell Rubygems to not install local documentation:

```
echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
```

Credits: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10

**Warning!!!**
There are issues with `Gnome-Shell`. See comment below.

Comment: It's worth noting that the user may have to run the following command as well, before installing ruby 2.2.0

sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

Comment: Warning! Added those lines to your .bash* files may make Gnome-Shell not load. I couldn't login until I removed those lines.

Comment: Thnaks, @Cerin. Added warning to post. Did you manage this issue? How do you add a path?

Comment: No, I never truly resolved this. I tried installing rvm instead, but apparently the installer (from https://get.rvm.io) detects Ubuntu and literally refuses to install, redirecting to a SO question which in turn recommends running the very same installer... So I decided instead to completely uninstall Ruby from my system and switch over all my Ruby tools to Python equivalents.

Comment: Is the gnome-shell issue related to how the PATH variable is being modified? I've always read that new paths should be appended to PATH, not prepended. I've also read that environment variables should be added to ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bashrc.

Comment: After the above steps to install ruby, you can use gem to install or use the ruby related things eg, 
1. sass - gem install sass
2. compass - gem install compass

Comment: I followed the procedure to the tee. However after installation, when I check the version it shows me ruby 1.9.3 is installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Vivek please try it again, I've updated rbenv references

Answer (score 207):

There is a PPA with up-to-date versions of Ruby 2.x for Ubuntu 12.04+:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ruby2.4

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Comment: How do I select `ruby` to be  `ruby2.3` though?

Comment: @njzk2 Try `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` and follow the instructions there. On a fresh installation without official Ubuntu ruby package, the PPA package configured `ruby` alias to `ruby2.3` automatically for me.

Comment: While this way is far easier to do, using a PPA is not really the 'best' way, PPAs can go away, often haven't been as carefully put together as official channels etc. A PPA is a repository one person has set up and runs themselves. Just be careful out there.

Answer (score 40):

Best is to install it using **rvm**(ruby version manager).
Run following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential make curl
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.bash_profile
rvm install ruby-2.1.4
```

Then check ruby versions installed and in use:

```
rvm list
rvm use --default ruby-2.1.4
```

Also you can directly add ruby bin path to PATH variable. Ruby is installed in

```
$HOME/.rvm/rubies export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin
```

Comment: Piping arbitrary code over the net is a bad idea. Here's a "Wall of Shame" showing offending websites: curlpipesh.tumblr.com

Comment: `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

Comment: JECompton: Better to talk to the folks at rvm about that, as this is the canonical method of installing rvm.

Answer (score 6):

Use **RVM** (Ruby Version Manager) to install and manage any versions of Ruby. You can have multiple versions of Ruby installed on the machine and you can easily select the one you want.

To install RVM type into terminal:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

And let it work. After that you will have RVM along with Ruby installed.

Source: [RVM Site](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: To install RVM, follow the directions on [their installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install). There is a lot more to using RVM than running cURL, and the installation page goes over that. It should be read before the installation to become familiar with what it's going to do, including troubleshooting steps.

Comment: @theTinMan Of course I fully agree with you. That's why I added their page as source so author of this thread can read more about it.

Comment: Well, the home page for RVM is one thing, but most of the RVM questions we have here could have been solved immediately if the people had read the whole installation page.

Comment: Piping arbitrary code over the net is a bad idea. Here's a "Wall of Shame" showing offending websites: curlpipesh.tumblr.com

Answer (score 5):

update ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Install rvm, which manages the ruby versions:

to install rvm use the following command.

```
 \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
 source ~/.bash_profile
 rvm install ruby-2.1.4
```

Check ruby versions installed and in use:

```
rvm list
rvm use --default ruby-2.1.4
```